# Convert the HTML string to array of DOM

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, facebox

I want to convert the following HTML string to array of DOM nodes. And I want to set the href value using .down function in prototypejs. Please help.!!

```
<div class="fl"> 
    <a id="detailsLink" class="jsDetailsLink" href="/profile/28/Gatwick">More user information</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is your question tagged `jquery`?

Comment: Is this possible to convert the html string to array of dom nodes in jquery?

Comment: @ Kiran: Yes. It's also possible to do it without any library at all. But you *specifically* said Prototype, so...

Comment: What can you see in the browser DOM?, use firebug of firefox or another debugger by browser.

Comment: If the HTML string is converted into array of DOM, to use the prototype.js to set the href value and to open the facebox. The below code of mine is to open the facebox. var link = div.down('a.jsDetailsLink'); link.href = '/ajax/?action=userInfoFull&id=' + location.id; new Facebox(link); please help.where div contains the returned array elements of DOM.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way with Prototype is to create an element and then set its HTML to the string:

```
var e = new Element('div');
e.update(theString);
e.down('#detailsLink').writeAttribute("href", "your new link");
```

...and then use `e`'s children for whatever it is you want the DOM elements for.

---

Your question is also tagged `jquery` for some reason, so here's a jQuery solution:

```
var elements = $(theString);
elements.find("#detailsLink").attr("href", "your new link");
```

Comment: If the HTML string is converted into array of DOM, to use the prototype.js to set the href value and to open the facebox. The below code of mine is to open the facebox. var link = div.down('a.jsDetailsLink'); link.href = '/ajax/?action=userInfoFull&id=' + location.id; new Facebox(link); please help. where div contains the returned array elements of DOM.